# Can I run a list of Robo Scripts?

Tags: android, android-testing, firebase-test-lab, android-unit-testing

Is there a way to run a list of Robo Scripts (locally or to Firebase Test Lab) instead of running them one by one?

The way to run Robo Scripts locally one at a time is the following:

`java -jar crawl_launcher.jar --apk-file your_app.apk --app-package-name your.app.package.name --android-sdk path/to/android/sdk -—robo-script-file generated_script.json`

Moreover, is it possible to stop the App Crawler when the Robo Script is completed? (e.g. with a command in the script). Now, when the App Crawler completes the steps of the script proceeds to explore the app as usual with random actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add

```
{
  "eventType": "TERMINATE_CRAWL"
}
```

as the last action in your Roboscript. It will stop Robo when Roboscript finishes.

Comment: When I add this, the whole Robo Script is totally ignored and the App Crawler starts to explore the app as usually. Could you please provide a url with the documentation of these eventTypes?

Comment: It usually means that Roboscript is not well formed. Most probably, a comma is missing after the action block preceding the action block you appended to you Roboscript. As for documentation - we are currently working on releasing it to external users.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/android/robo-scripts-reference#execution-options

This json is malformed, @StanislavNegara Do you work for Firebase Test Lab?

Comment: Execution options are a header block preceding a Roboscript in a file. Although the resulting file is a malformed JSON as a whole, execution options block and the Roboscript block are processed separately as well formed JSON.